# Update associated 'latest' model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the following two models in my application, `Product` and `Price`

A `Product` describes the product (`name`, `description`, etc.) and the`Price` has a `value`, `first_seen_at` (datetime) and `last_seen_at` (datetime).

A `Product` has_many `Prices`.

The idea is that when a the price of a product changes, the latest `Price` record is updated:

- If the `value` of the new price is the same as the existing price, `last_seen_at` is updated
- If the `value` of the new price is different to the existing price, a new `Price` record is created with the new details

I want to be able to access the latest price of a product, so currently use `product.prices.last.value` where `product` is any given product from the database

Is there a better way of achieving this? To add a price to the database, I'm currently performing the following actions:

1. Find product in database
2. Find latest price for that product
3. Check for difference in price
4. Either update price record or create a new price record

I know I could store the latest_price in the `Product` record, but the data would then be duplicated...

Comment: `If value is the same, ` the same to which?

Comment: "When a price is found" - is this some sort of price comparison app? I think you need to give a kind of high level description of how this is supposed to work.

Comment: I have made some edits to clarify - the idea is that the price of a product will change. But I will be pushing the latest price to the app through a request. This request then will get processed... has the value changed? etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `has_one` to provide access to the "last" price, but it's hardly shorter than simply using `prices.last`:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prices
  has_one :latest_price, -> { order('id desc').limit(1) }, class_name: 'Price'
end

# Your code
product.prices.last.value

# My code
product.latest_price.value
```

Generally I would prefer the `prices.last` approach. You should be moving all of your "Create or update" logic into the model however, so the way in which you access the last value shouldn't matter as much. It should be roughly as simple as `product.prices.last.update_value`.